# pandas replace boolean value with string or integer

Tags: pandas, replace, boolean

This is snipett of my code with column values comparison:

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame({'coname1':['Apple','Yahoo','Gap Inc'],'coname2':['Apple', 'Google', 'Apple']})
df['eq'] =df.apply(lambda row: row['coname1'] == row['coname2'],axis=1)
```

The problem is that I am interested with `Character (True='Y' or False = 'N')` or `Integer (True= 1 or False = 0)` values.

Option `df.replace(['True', 'False'],[1,0])` doesn't work
Thank you

Comment: pass a dict to use `replace` on the df: `df.replace({'True':1,'False':0})`

Comment: You could also do this in your function itself: `df['eq'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['coname1'] == row['coname2'] else 0, axis=1)`

Comment: I've been struggling with replace boolean values with integer too! converting a boolean call to int seems to be the best way, right now, if you want 0 or 1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When assigning the `'eq'` column, use `atype(int)`.  The int conversion turns `True` into `1` and `False` into `0`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'coname1': ['Apple','Yahoo','Gap Inc'], 'coname2':['Apple', 'Google', 'Apple']})
df['eq'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['coname1'] == row['coname2'], axis=1).astype(int)
```

---

For characters

```
df['eq'] = np.where(df['eq'], 'Y', 'N')
df
```

[image]

Comment: typo in line 1. `astype()` .. [panda docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)